# How to solve this convex optimization?

Tags: scipy, convex-optimization, convex, quadratic-programming

It is simple, I know but I have little understanding of convex optimization yet

Problem definition:

1. Objective function is II b - Aw II norm 2
2. a vector of unknown [w1, w2, ..., wn]
3. a data matrix A (m x n), each row has n components([ai1, ai2, ..., ain]), m is the number of measures. ai1, ai2, ..., ain are themselves highly correlated to each other
4. constraints  wi >= 0 and sum of wi is 1, basically wi can be interpreted as weights

which python or matlab package could I use, maybe ?

Comment: What is the objective function? I only see constraints.

Comment: Objective is  II  b - Aw  II norm 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem in [Quadratic Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_programming).

- Python - [CVXOPT](http://cvxopt.org/)
- Matlab - [quadprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html)